# Ошибка при запуске Open Server

Tags: openserver

при запуске сервера появляется окно с ошибкой [image: ошибка]

Установил последнюю версию сервера, не помогло. Попытался создать этот фаил, он отобразился как "hosts (2)", т.е. сам фаил есть, но при этом в папке его нет.

Answer (score 0):

Всё решилось созданием нового пустого файла hosts